# Attach sources in Eclipse Plug-in Dependencies container

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

We use eclipse and m2e to work with a tycho-based plugin.
Our problem is the sources of the dependencies are not attached:

[image: Image illustrating the problem, plugin dependencies does not have correct sources]

Is there any way to make PDE/m2e download sources automatically and attach them to the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install this [pde.source.lookup](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pde-source-lookup) plugin, that will look for matching source bundles in the available p2 repositories of your Eclipse installation, just like m2e does for Maven dependencies.

If the source jar exists in one the p2 repositories and it doesn't work for you (really it should), please open a bug to its [issue tracker](https://github.com/fbricon/pde.source.lookup/issues).

Now, if that doesn't work, i.e. the jar doesn't come from a p2 repository, another alternative is to install [JBoss Tools' Maven source lookup feature](http://tools.jboss.org/features/maven.html#enhanced-source-lookup-mechanism), which is very similar to m2e's mechanism, but a bit more robust and more complete, as it'll look for sources in Maven Central and different Nexus repository managers, based on the SHA1 checksum of your jar. It's downside is it'll bring down a bunch of dependencies in Eclipse you don't necessarily need (JBoss Servers stuff)

Answer (score 0):

When PDE creates the Plug-in Dependencies classpath container, source attachments are added based on what is known to org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.SourceLocationManager.  While older source models are still supported (extension point), source is now typically delivered via source bundle.  A source bundle will have a manifest entry describing what it provides source for.

```
Eclipse-SourceBundle: org.apache.ant;version="1.9.2.v201307241445";roo
 ts:="libsrc"
```

If a source bundle is available for what you need source for, you can add that source bundle to your target platform and PDE will attach the source when creating the classpath container.

Alternatively, you can temporarily attach a source zip/folder to the entry.

PDE does not provide a service to search for source.  One other option could be the "Add Artifact to Target Platform" dialog (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A), which can search through known p2 repositories for the needed source bundle and add it to your target platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A shows me an empty list. How can i add source bundles?

Comment: If you have a source bundle (downloaded an SDK for example), you can add it via the Target Platform preference page.  Edit your active target platform and add the location containing the bundles.  If you are using a software site (p2) based target platform, when selecting the content, there is an option to "Include source if available" which will search the repository for associated source bundles.